# Как убрать кавычки в JSON?

Tags: android, json, sqlite

У меня есть БД из нее получаю JSON следующим способом

```
    String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.apps/databases/";
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DBHelper.DATABASE_NAME;// Set path to your database
    String myTable = DBHelper.TABLE_CONTACT;//Set name of your table
    SQLiteDatabase myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    String searchQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + myTable;
    Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery(searchQuery, null );

    JSONArray json = new JSONArray();
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
        int totalColumn = cursor.getColumnCount();
        JSONObject rowObject = new JSONObject();

        for(int i=0 ;  i< totalColumn ; i++) {
            if(cursor.getColumnName(i) != null) {
                try {
                    if(cursor.getString(i) != null) {
                        Log.d("TAG_NAME", cursor.getString(i));
                        rowObject.put(cursor.getColumnName(i), cursor.getString(i));
                    } else {
                        rowObject.put(cursor.getColumnName(i), "");
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e) {
                    Log.d("TAG_NAME", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
        json.put(rowObject);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    Log.d("TAG_NAME_ALL", json.toString());
    return json.toString();
```

JSON получается какой необходим, за исключением одного значения **latlng**.

Я получаю - **"latlng":"[54.601530521,55.918132215051]"**

Нужно получить - **"latlng":[54.601530521,55.918132215051]**

Как избавиться от кавычек?

Comment: Ошибка тута `rowObject.put(cursor.getColumnName(i), cursor.getString(i));` проверку поставьте, что бы если `latlng` то что бы она добавляла rowObject.put(cursor.getColumnName(i), cursor.getDouble); или создайте для каждого Lat и Long отдельно объект JsonObject и все будет нормально

Comment: if(cursor.getColumnName(i) == "latlng"){
                                rowObject.put(cursor.getColumnName(i), cursor.getDouble(i));
                            } else {
                                rowObject.put(cursor.getColumnName(i), cursor.getString(i));    

Не помогло :(

Comment: ответ [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34300800/how-to-remove-the-double-quotes-in-the-json)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

из комментарий и [оригинал из stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34301531/4953620)

---

Если вам нужно быстро перевести строку на double, хоть и с грязным кодом, тогда вы можете сделать так:

```
String s = "[12.3456789,98.7654321]";
String trimmed = s.substring(1, s.length()-1);
String[] parts = trimmed.split(",");
double lat = Double.parseDouble(parts[0]);
double lng = Double.parseDouble(parts[1]);
Log.d("latlng", "lat="+lat+"  lng="+lng);
```

Это не красиво, но работает.